# Is it possible to run cmd commands over rdp?

Tags: windows, rdp, mstsc

I have multiply computers in my network which i need to automate some script. the only port can be used for that is rdp (3389), and I need to find a way to run commands over thid rdp port, without the GUI stuff.

what i am looking for is something like winRM, where i can enter remote session in powershell/cmd.

note: I cant use winRM/smb/rpc for that task. only rdp.
and if it won't disconnect the user logged in to the computer it will be even better...

so is something like this possible?
thanks!

Comment: Confused!! Are you need to change port 3389 to something else or anything else please add some code if you have tried!!

Comment: No. the port stays the same. i haven't tried anything because it's a theoretical question. i need to execute cmd commands over RDP, that's all.